# Função - Alteração de formato de data em formulário preenchido X em branco

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida. Preciso corrigir uma data em um formulário, porem se o campo estiver vazio, ele passa reto pela função e não executa. Se o mesmo estiver previamente preenchido, ele faz a alteração.

Inicialmente realizei assim, sem a validação do campo vazio:

```
  $(document).ready(function AcertaDataInsp() {

  var data = $("#dataInspecao").val();
  var aData = data.split("-");
  var datacompleta = aData[2]+'/'+aData[1]+'/'+aData[0];
  $("#dataInspecao").val(datacompleta);  

  });
```

Minha dúvida é, como faço a função pra executar somente se o campo estiver preenchido? Hoje se executo a função acima, no formulário ele preenche assim "undefined/undefined/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi, basta colocar um `if` verificando se o valor de `data` tem alguma coisa e executar o resto do código. Se estiver vazio, não entra no `if` e não executa o resto do código:

```
$(document).ready(function AcertaDataInsp() {

   var data = $("#dataInspecao").val();

   if(data){
      var aData = data.split("-");
      var datacompleta = aData[2]+'/'+aData[1]+'/'+aData[0];
      $("#dataInspecao").val(datacompleta);  
   }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou desta forma. O detalhe do campo indefinido desapareceu. Vou testar em situações de data preenchida também.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, William. Esse input que você está tentando formatar é do tipo `date` ? Se não for, recomendo que você utilize o input date juntamente com o evento `.on('select', callback)`. Assim, você conseguirá formatar a data com a classe `Date` do próprio JS, da maneira que você desejar. Ou de uma maneira mais simples:

```
$(document).ready(function AcertaDataInsp() {
    $("dataInspecao").on('select', function(event) {
        var data = $("#dataInspecao").val();
        var aData = data.split("-");
        var datacompleta = aData[2]+'/'+aData[1]+'/'+aData[0];
        $("#dataInspecao").val(datacompleta);  
    });
});
```

Comment: O formato que vem do banco está formatado no padrão data internacional em forma de String.